# Spring boot REST service set Kafka topic properties at runtime inside the controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-restcontroller

I am new to Spring boot and kafka. I have simple rest service that when called consumes messages from kafka topic. Have one custom config class, controller. Want to know how can I set the properties at runtime e.g. ***MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG***, ***AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG*** etc. I see KafkaConfig only gets executed at startup time. How can I set the above properties at runtime i.e. based on some query params want to set these properties, any idea on how I can do that inside **getMessagesFromKafkaTopic** method at runtime. Here is my controller, kafkaConfig

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
 
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {   
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.server}")
    private String server;
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.groupid}")
    private String gid;
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.enablecommit}")
    private String enablecommit;
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.ommitinterval}")
    private String commitint;
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.sessiontimeout}")
    private String timeout;
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.maxrecordspoll}")
    private String maxPollRecords;
    
    @Value("${kafka.con.offsetReset}")
    private String offsetReset;
    
    
    /**
     * ConsumerFactory
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, gid);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, enablecommit);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, commitint);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, timeout);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords); 
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offsetReset);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
    
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object>(configs);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }
    
}
```

**KafkaConsumerController.java**

```
    import java.text.Format;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
    public class KafkaConsumerController {
        @Autowired
        private ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory;
    
        @Autowired
        private ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/consume", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void getMessagesFromKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("batchsize") int batchsize) {
    
            System.out.println("********* batchsize " + batchsize);


//here would like to set MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to the value coming in as param

            
            Consumer<Object, Object> con = null;
    
            try {
                
                con = consumerFactory.createConsumer();
                con.subscribe(Collections.singleton("demotopic"));
                
                int count = 0;
    
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = con.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
                    System.out.println("****** Record Count ******* : " + records.count());
                    
                    if(records.count() == 0) {
                        count++;
                        if(count > 3) {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            continue;
                    }
    
                    for (ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record : records) {
                        System.out.println("Message: " + record.value());
                        System.out.println("Message offset: " + record.offset());
                        System.out.println("Message headers: " + record.timestamp());
    
                        Date date = new Date(record.timestamp());
                        Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                        System.out.println("Message date: " + format.format(date));
                    }
                    con.commitSync();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                con.close();
            }
            
            System.out.println("********* END **********");
        }
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
kafka.con.server=localhost:9092
kafka.con.groupid=my-first-consumer-group
kafka.con.enablecommit=false
kafka.con.ommitinterval=1000
kafka.con.sessiontimeout=30000
kafka.con.maxrecordspoll=5
kafka.con.offsetReset=earliest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `con = consumerFactory.createConsumer();` use:

```java
/**
 * Create a consumer with an explicit group id; in addition, the
 * client id suffix is appended to the clientIdPrefix which overrides the
 * {@code client.id} property, if present. In addition, consumer properties can
 * be overridden if the factory implementation supports it.
 * @param groupId the group id.
 * @param clientIdPrefix the prefix.
 * @param clientIdSuffix the suffix.
 * @param properties the properties to override.
 * @return the consumer.
 * @since 2.2.4
 */
Consumer<K, V> createConsumer(@Nullable String groupId, @Nullable String clientIdPrefix,
        @Nullable String clientIdSuffix, @Nullable Properties properties);
```

Which allows you to override consumer properties via the `properties` parameter.

Comment: I tried below but still it doesn't set the property, don't know if there's anything I'm missing ******** Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, batchsize);
con = consumerFactory.createConsumer("my-first-consumer-group", null, null, properties);} ******** what is clientIdPrefix & clientIdSuffix I don't have defined in configuration.

Comment: What version are you using? In older versions, we only look at String-valued properties. Try `properties.setProperty(..., "" + batchSize)`. You can leave the client id prefix and suffix as `null`; they are used to assemble the optional `client.id` property.

Comment: have one more questions. As I have a REST Service that will be invoked on-demand basis, have one topic with one partition only. REST Service is the only consumer. Want to see which listner to use KafkaMessageListenerContainer or ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.

Comment: ? You are not using a listener container, you are managing and polling the consumer yourself.

Comment: Noticed removing while(true) and keeping poll(5) seconds every-time I call the service it never consumes any messages bumping poll value to 15 seconds I see messages been getting consumed, is there a recommended value if don't want to use while. The reason is want to return the exact messages that  are set to MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG if using while loop it will continue till break occurs. My message size is around 5kb and in one request/response max messages want to consume and send to client is 500.

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in comments; better to ask a new question. It's better to use `consumer.assign()` instead of `consumer.subscribe()` for your use case - then you don't have to wait for group management to assign the partitions. Unfortunately, there is no `FETCH_MIN_RECORDS` config. You can approximate it with `FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG` together with `FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG`. If your records are similar sizes you should be able to come close to what you want, but you will still probably need the while loop.